# javolution xml modification

Tags: xml, javolution

I tryed to modify an attribute value in created xml file.
I have to use javolution api to manage XML files.

I create an XML file using XMLStreamWriter, I add several components at the begining of my tool execution, but i want to modify some values after. How can i reach these attributes in order to modify?

For exemple i create EXECUTION_START and EXECUTION_STOP attributes at the start of my execution. But i have to update the EXECUTION_STOP value at the end.

Do you have some ideas?
Or did I have to close the stream and reopen it?
And what should be used to open an XML file, to change the content.

Tks